# Form Post Request with Authentication Middleware throws error 419 Page Expired in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a form to create a card, this form is public, when a person fills out the form and wants to publish their card, they are asked to log in or if they are a new user to register.

I suppose that when the login is requested, the token that was immersed in the form expires and throws the 419 error.

**How can I login and update the token to avoid error 419?**

I am not an expert in Laravel so any suggestions would be appreciated.

[reference diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO1oe.png)

here a part of the code that I have implemented

**Login via AJAX**

```
$(function () {
        
        $('#login-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    
            e.preventDefault();
    
            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.prop('action');
            let data = form.serializeArray();
            console.log(data);
    
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                },
                url: url,
                data: form.serializeArray(),
                success: function(json) {
                    console.log('OK')
                },
                error: function(json) {
                    console.log('NOK')
                    alert(json);
                },
            });
    
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('create.card.newuser')->only('store');
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['create', 'store']);
    }
```

**Middleware "CreateCardIfNewUser"**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! Auth::user() ) 
        {
            return redirect()->route('digital_card.create')->with('openModalLogin', true)
                ->withInput($request->all());
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

**View 'layouts.app'**

```
@if(session()->has('openModalLogin'))
    <script>
        $('#login-modal').modal({
            show: true
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `csrf_token` to the data:

```json
…
data : { 
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your error is due to the absence of csrf token. this solution is not only valid on this problem. each time you will have this problem of 419 then you must immediately think of the csrf token

```
data: {
         _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must always add a csrf token to each submission otherwise you will always get this error

```
data: {
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
   },
```